# Dual Booting Ubuntu 16.04.6 with Windows 10 on a HP Pavilion laptop

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, grub, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to build my own mobile manipulator robot, and would like to use [Robot Operating System (ROS)](https://www.ros.org) to control multiple Arduinos in tandem, wirelessly. All this is on a HP Pavilion laptop.

In order to have [Robot Operating System (ROS)](https://www.ros.org) work, I need to download Ubuntu. I have tried everything I could possibly think of, but I always get stuck on the GRUB loading screen when I try to boot it up.

Here are the steps I followed:

1. Download 64-bit Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.6 disk image (iso).
2. Open up "Disk Management" in Windows and Create a 60 GB Simple Partition for Ubuntu to exist on.
3. Use Rufus to flash the disk image to a USB Drive (16 GB).
4. Once Rufus does its stuff, restart the computer and select "boot from USB -> Ubuntu" from the startup menu

At this point, I am met with a terminal-esque interface called "GRUB". I followed several tutorials on the internet, but every time I try to boot it up, one of 2 things happens:

1. My USB drive isn't recognized even though it's plugged in.
2. If it is recognized, the necessary `vmlinuz` and `initrd.img` files are nowhere to be found. Furthermore, I don't even have a `/boot` directory or `/dev` directory.

Any suggestions at all are greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about re-setting your disk partitions to Windows only, then let the Ubuntu installer partition the disk? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot See the section `Manual partitioning`. Further help on resizing Windows partitions https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoResizeWindowsPartitions

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi